# Find the most recent sales record for specific items in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to find an item most recent sales record.
As I want to just type the item code it would should the record.

My data looks like this:

```
code date     sales
134  10/01/17  100
```

I was trying this code:

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(A2:A9),A2:C9,3,0)
```

But this one would not get the latest value according to the date?
As the date is in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example sample data is in cells A2:C8, Put Item Code in E2 and get the latest Sales in F1.

Please ensure that there's at least one spare row above your data range for this solution to work correctly. Usually you will have a Header row above your data and hence there should be no issue. That's where the `-ROW($B$1)` part of the formula comes into picture. This is not required if your data starts at Row 1 itself.

Put the following formula in F2 and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the Formula Bar to create an Array Formula. Now the formula shall be enclosed in Curly Braces.

```
=INDEX($C2:$C$8,MIN(IF($A$2:$A$8&$B$2:$B$8=E2&MAX(IF($A$2:$A$8=E2,$B$2:$B$8)),ROW($B$2:$B$8)-ROW($B$1),9^99)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it works! And you  explained very clearly.  Just wondering why at the end is 9^99?

Comment: The solution is based on INDEX Function which in tern receives the MIN of Array of Row Numbers from the search array (Concatenation of Col A & B). If match is found it returns the row number else always return a very large number way beyond the Max Rows offered by Excel. This way solution works fine even if put into last set of Rows on worksheet. In the above example it receives MIN (9^99,9^99,..., 6, 9^99) which is 6 and Index returns 6th element of the array which is the intended value in this case for the Item Code and Latest Sales date as in Col A & B.

Comment: Really appreciate you explained everything very clearly to me. Thanks a lot once again.